# NSTableView Delegate Methods aren't getting called by .reloadData()

Tags: delegates, nstableview, reloaddata

This one is stumping me, though I know it's going to be simple.

I have multiple ViewControllers, each of which has a table view to display a list of data specific to the controller. Three out of the 4 work perfectly.  However, I'm clearly missing something in the forth, because the Delegate methods are never getting called by .reloadData().  No compiler errors, just never calls my delegate methods for some reason.

Here is my class setup including my connected outlet variable:

```
class performanceViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate {

//--------------------------------
// OUTLET CONNECTIONS
//--------------------------------

@IBOutlet weak var displayPerformanceList: NSTableView!
```

I've also implemented the following two delegate functions:

```
func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
```

and

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
```

but for some reason, neither of these functions are called when I execute my custom function:

```
func redrawViews() {
    self.displayPerformanceList.reloadData()
}
```

(Note: the .reloadData is wrapped in a function because it will be doing other things as well that I haven't added in yet.)

I added breakpoints in both of the delegate functions, which is how I know they are not getting executed.

I know this is going to turn out to be something stupid that I missed since I have it working in three other custom viewControllers... I just can't for the life of me figure out what I missed...

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

:)

Answer (score 2):

Well, after poking around a bit more and following some tutorials, I found my problem.  I completely forgot to link the NSTableView Data Source and Delegate to the controller in the Interface Builder!

Doh!

Leaving this question/answer here in case anyone else gets caught by this. :)

Comment: Just got burned by this one too. Thanks!